# Get Resized Width and Height of img Element with max-width Property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I dynamically create `img` elements using JavaScript.

These elements has CSS `max-width` property so they are resized.

I tried the following code.

```
function addPhoto(title, imgPath, tags) {
    ...
    var photoImg = document.createElement('img');
    photoImg.src = imgPath;
    console.log(photoImg.naturalHeight);
    console.log(photoImg.naturalWidth);
    ...
}
```

If I run the code above, it prints width and height of an original image.

How can I get resized `width` and `height` of the `img` element?

Comment: Remove the `natural`.

Comment: @JonUleis Wow...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @JonUleis!

```
function addPhoto(title, imgPath, tags) {
    ...
    var photoImg = document.createElement('img');
    photoImg.src = imgPath;
    console.log(photoImg.height);
    console.log(photoImg.width);
    photoImg.onload = function() {
        console.log(this.height);
        console.log(this.width);
    }
}
```

The first two `console.log`s print 'undefined'.
However, the last two `console.log`s print resized `width` and `height` of the `img` element.